# DataGrid Selection Missing Items

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I have a DataGrid with virtualization turned on. I have the IsSelected property of the cells in the DataGrid bound to my model. The binding works in most cases (meaning if I click cells that are currently shown on the screen it works fine). However, if I use the "select all" button or use the keyboard (CTRL+SHIFT+Down) when there are lots of rows...it seems to miss some of the data. The IsSelected property won't get set.

My gut tells me this is something with the virtualization but I can't turn virtualization off because it will be far too slow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, reason because it doesn't work is virtualization.

To make it work you are going to have to manually synchronize [DataGrid.SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx) and a collection of selected cell models by using [DataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcellschanged.aspx) event.

Comment: Example code to get me started? I'm not quite following how I would "manually synchronize"

Comment: Can you first explain how you bound DataGridCell.IsSelected to your model? I am asking because DataContext of DataGridCell is a single item from your model collection that is bound to DataGrid.SelectedItems, not a property value for a single item. Do you maybe bind DataGridCell.IsSelected to your "DataGridRowViewModel".IsSelected property?

Comment: I have a mistake in my question. It should be "bound to DataGrid.ItemsSource", not "bound to DataGrid.SelectedItems".